# How to demonstrate frame dragging through the Kerr metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I derived the Kerr metric, but in a form which doesn't seem to relate to frame dragging. I have been trying this for some time, so how do we relate the Kerr metric to frame dragging?

Comment: What form of the metric do you have then? And what have you tried? For instance, what do you take frame dragging to be mathematically? You should show what you've done so we know where to start with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, frame dragging arises out of the off-diagonal terms in the Kerr metric. [This pdf](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/astro490/lectures/lecture490_ch13.pdf) gives a brief outline on how to calculate frame dragging from the metric.